# Help understanding the dimensions of the 1N4007-SMD's datasheet

Tags: datasheet, dimensions

I'm trying to understand what are the real dimensions of the following diode:

http://www.sycelectronica.com.ar/semiconductores/1N4007-SMD.pdf

For simplicity, here is a screenshot of the relevant part from the PDF:

[image: 1N4007-SMD dimensions, taken from the PDF]

By looking at the dimensions, one can notice that there is a pair of values for each dimension. For example, the first horizontal length is 4.597 / 3.988.

What is the meaning of those numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: Related, but not exactly a duplicate: [do-i-need-to-worry-about-min-max-footprint-length-values-in-datasheets](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25005/do-i-need-to-worry-about-min-max-footprint-length-values-in-datasheets/25025)

Comment: Do you know what tolerance implies?  Mfg variances and design changes but non-metric originally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers represent the maximum and minimum dimensions. The somewhat silly number of digits indicates that they were converted from hard Imperialist measurements.

For example 4.597 max to 3.988 min (mm) was originally 181 to 157 thousandths of an inch.

Answer (score 3):

They are maximum and minimum limits.